# Empty array returned from api database when publishing to azure

Tags: database, azure, publish

I've recently tried to publish a very simple API which runs with a local SQL server database to Azure through Visual Studio, but it only returns an empty array when entering the correct route.

[Empty array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaIxs.png)

I already included the dependancy to Azure and connected it to an Azure database, but no data is returned although I clearly see the data in my local db. The API runs as it should when running it locally and works fine.

I've seen some tutorials on publishing to Azure from VS with an API and a database but nothing seems to resolve the issue

Comment: Could you add the code/approach what you tried in VS? This information will help to understand the issue better.